# Java Async Sockets multithread performance

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

I need to question about 11M nameservers and to find out which of them alive. In Java I use async sockets to send udp-requests and everything ok until I try to use multiple threads. The speed rises proportionally, but positive responses decrease dramatically, although I use a high-perfomance 16-core cluster.
I create a separate channel per thread and see no obvious reason why this happening. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong and is it okay to use different async sockets in threads?

Here's some code. So I have a lot of threads with id and it's list of hosts, each of them do the following:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    DatagramChannel channel = null;
    try {
        channel = DatagramChannel.open();
        InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress(Settings.LOCAL_PORT+id);
        channel.socket().bind(isa);
        channel.configureBlocking(false);
        Selector selector = Selector.open(); 
        channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE);
        ByteBuffer outBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(Settings.QUERY);
        ByteBuffer inBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(200);
        while (true) {          
            selector.select();
            Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {                
                SelectionKey key = iterator.next();
                iterator.remove();
                if (!key.isValid()) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (key.isReadable()) {
                    inBuffer.clear();
                    channel.receive(inBuffer);
                    inBuffer.flip();
                    inCounter++;
                    //some analize of response
                    continue;
                }
                if (key.isWritable()) {
                    if (outCounter < hosts.size()) {
                        channel.send(outBuffer, new InetSocketAddress(hosts.get(outCounter), Settings.DNS_PORT));
                        outBuffer.flip();
                        outCounter++;
                    } 
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (channel != null)
                try {
                    channel.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }                       
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Our psychic powers aren't that great.  Some code might help.

Answer (score 0):

As UDP is an unreliable protocol, you have to be careful not to overload your system or your network buffers or packets will be lost.  How to do this is likely to be sensitive to a number of factors, so it doesn't surprise me that doing this a little differently could improve your response rate.

Are you using UDP Datagrams or TCP Sockets? Why are trying to poll 11 million names servers?